# how to import variable from a different file class function

Tags: python

```
  self.assertFalse(b.__is_manual) AttributeError: 'BaseResource' object has no attribute '_Resources__is_manual'
```

My `test_resources.py` is

```
class Resources(TestCase):
    def test_disable_manual_mode(self):
        self.assertFalse(b.__is_manual)
if __name__=='__main__':
    b = base.BaseResource()
    unittest.main()
```

And My `base.py` is

```
class BaseResource(object):
    def __init__(self, index=0, parent=None, **kwargs):
        self.__is_manual = False
    def disable_manual_mode(self):
        self.__is_manual = False
```

Both are in same directory I want to import `__is_manual` in `test_resouces.py`

How do i do it.

I have tried `b.__is_manual` but it is giving error(mentioned above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)

> “Private” instance variables that cannot be accessed except from inside an object don’t exist in Python. However, there is a convention that is followed by most Python code: a name prefixed with an underscore (e.g. _spam) should be treated as a non-public part of the API (whether it is a function, a method or a data member). It should be considered an implementation detail and subject to change without notice.
>   The instantiation of object must be inside the test class.

When naming the attribute to `__is_manual`, you are defining it as a "protected" attribute, and you can not access it. Simplify your code.

```
class BaseResource(object):
    def __init__(self, index=0, parent=None, **kwargs):
        self.is_manual = False

    def disable_manual_mode(self):
        self.is_manual = False
```

Also, the instantiation of object must be inside the test class.

```
class Resources(TestCase):
    def test_disable_manual_mode(self):
        b = base.BaseResource()
        self.assertFalse(b.is_manual)

if __name__=='__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: @AbhishekYadav I have improved the answer.

Comment: But if i have multiple methods then i need to do instantiation of object multiple times

Answer (score 0):

We can't access __is_manual. Because we can't access a variable starting with __ (double underscore).